# Split content from one .csv to multiple files based on content using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, search, import-csv, export-csv

I've got a .csv file with two types of rows. The first one contains the header-information. It always starts with `AB`. The second type contains the content. This one always starts with `CD`.
There can be multiple content-rows after each header-row (always at least one). They belong together until the next header-row (starting with `AB` again).

Example:

```
header1; header2; header3; header4; header5; header6; header7
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; BC987654321; EUR
CD; 456789; 22.24; Text; SW;
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; BC987654322; EUR
CD; 354345; 85.45; Text; SW;
CD; 123556; 94.63; Text; SW;
CD; 354564; 12.34; Text; SW;
CD; 135344; 32.23; Text; SW;
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; BC987654323; EUR
CD; 354564; 12.34; Text; SW;
CD; 852143; 34.97; Text; SW;
```

How Can I split this file into several .csv-files - one for each header-row (AB) - using PowerShell. My desired outcome would be

`BC987654321.csv`

```
header1; header2; header3; header4; header5; header6; header7
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; BC987654321; EUR
CD; 456789; 22.24; Text; SW;
```

`BC987654322.csv`

```
header1; header2; header3; header4; header5; header6; header7
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; BC987654322; EUR
CD; 354345; 85.45; Text; SW;
CD; 123556; 94.63; Text; SW;
CD; 354564; 12.34; Text; SW;
CD; 135344; 32.23; Text; SW;
```

and `BC987654323.csv`

```
header1; header2; header3; header4; header5; header6; header7
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; BC987654323; EUR
CD; 354564; 12.34; Text; SW;
CD; 852143; 34.97; Text; SW;
```

I am not used to PowerShell at all - so I'll appreciate a newb-friendly solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what youve tried?

Comment: Is this a real example of your CSV file? Where is the data and why do we only see headers? What is your desired output?

Comment: @Theo Those were not the headers but just randomly picked cell-names. I just edited the question so the example looks more like the actual file now.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I am currently reading how PowerShell works in general as I've mentioned in the question, I got literally zero experience in using it yet. I've been able to add a header to the file at least (there is none in the provided file), so it might be easier to work with the collumns from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to split the csv on every row where 'header1' is equal to 'AB' and then use what is in that row under 'header6' for the output file name.

```
$path = 'D:\Test'
$fileIn = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'input.csv'
$fileOut = $null   # will get a value in the loop
$splitValue = 'AB' # the header1 value that decides to start a new file
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $fileIn -Delimiter ';'
# get an array of the column headers
$allHeaders = $csv[0].PsObject.Properties.Name
foreach ($item in $csv) {
    if ($item.header1 -eq $splitValue) { 
        # start a new file
        $fileOut = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}.csv' -f $item.header6)
        # create the new csv file with the first row of data already in it
        $item | Select-Object $allHeaders | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
    }
    else {
        # rows with header1 not 'AB' are added to that file
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($fileOut)) {
            Write-Warning "Could not find a starting row (header1 = '$splitValue') for the file"
        }
        else {
            $item | Select-Object $allHeaders | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Delimiter ';' -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, change the paths to match your environment.

Output:

**BC987654321.csv**

```
"header1";"header2";"header3";"header4";"header5";"header6";"header7"
"AB";"12345";"AB123456789";"10.03.2021";"GT";"BC987654321";"EUR"
"CD";"456789";"22.24";"Text";"SW";"";
```

**BC987654322.csv**

```
"header1";"header2";"header3";"header4";"header5";"header6";"header7"
"AB";"12345";"AB123456789";"10.03.2021";"GT";"BC987654322";"EUR"
"CD";"354345";"85.45";"Text";"SW";"";
"CD";"123556";"94.63";"Text";"SW";"";
"CD";"354564";"12.34";"Text";"SW";"";
"CD";"135344";"32.23";"Text";"SW";"";
```

**BC987654323.csv**

```
"header1";"header2";"header3";"header4";"header5";"header6";"header7"
"AB";"12345";"AB123456789";"10.03.2021";"GT";"BC987654323";"EUR"
"CD";"354564";"12.34";"Text";"SW";"";
"CD";"852143";"34.97";"Text";"SW";;
```

Comment: I get an error on `$item | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Delimiter ';' -Append` saying that Path is NULL or empty.

Comment: @Nerevar.de no, it means there was no starting row where header1 contained value `AB`. I have only your example to go on, in real life you need to change `AB` to what the really makes for the first line in the file to split on. I have updated my answer so now it will show a message about that and added a new variable `$splitValue` so you can simply set that to what is in the real file.

Comment: Yea, I got that one. I also changed that before your update. But even your solution with the new variable has the same effect. With your edited code it now shows the warning instead of the error messages. Even tried to change the file's content to AB to test it out from the other side.

Comment: @Nerevar.de Then please edit your question and show the first 3 or 4 lines of the file as it actually is. Using the example works.

Comment: My bad. I've been missing to change "header1" which is obvisoulsly different in the real files as well. I've also created one last question regarding merging those exact lines. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566801/ Would be glad if you check it out aswell. Thanks again!